# CSS not working in root installation after Akeeba Restore

Tags: akeebabackup

I restore the latest Joomla using Akeeba in the root directory. The resulting home page has no CSS formatting, and any links clicked will result in wrong url. When I create a testing subdirectory and restore using Akeeba again, the homepage is working as normal.

I believe it is the routing config file that cause the problem. For example, the website that I have problem with is http://classwebhost.com. If I click on any link, I get an error 404. When I check the URL, what I saw is **classwebhost.com/classwebhost.com/classwebhost.com/the-link-url**. It seems that the root domain is repeated three times. But when I rename the php.ini file, the same problem exists. An identical Akeeba backup was restored to http://classwebhost.com/testing/ and everything works as usual.

I try to change the php.ini name, but it doesn't work. What should I do?

Solution:
I downgrade the PHP version from 5.6 to 5.4 and it works. WHMCS works with PHP 5.4 as of now.

Comment: Try disabling Joomla SEF URL's in the Global Configuration, then try **temporarily** removing your `htaccess` file to see if the problem still occurs

Comment: I can't login to administrator's backend to change the Global Configuration. I only get a white page.

Comment: In which case you can change the value in your `configuration.php` then

Comment: @Standstill please add your solution as an answer so this question can be resolved.